# Macbook Pro Retina Version (late 2013) - no sound or webcam on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, macbook-pro-retina

I have a new Macbook Pro retina (late 2013 model) running Ubuntu 13.10. I can't get the sound to work. I have tried the solution here , but it's not changing anything. I also tried the following series of commands, but they don't change anything, either:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

When I start the computer and the login screen appears, I hear one sound - the sound Ubuntu usually makes when there's an error. After I log in, however, I can't hear anything again. The sound works perfectly on OSX - it's only Ubuntu that seems to be having this problem. Is there anything else I can try to get the sound to work?

Comment: time to move towards ubuntu 14.04 lts release. Have you tried that?

Comment: @NKN: I upgraded, but it didn't fix the sound...

Comment: @NKN: Never mind, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to see if `pulseaudio` is actually using the correct sound card? I had a similar problem and solved it by reading the Arch Linux [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x#Sound)

> sometimes it thinks HDMI is the default sound card; to solve this problem, install pavucontrol and set Analog Stereo as the fallback device.

Alternatively you can do this via `alsamixer` and select the correct sound card via `F6` (once you are inside `alsamixer`). If you have selected the correct sound card, a series of volume bars should appear, use the arrow keys to select "master" and adjust the volume with up and down arrow keys.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: How about webcam.